# How to handle null exception in my case

Tags: java

I have defined a function:

```
public MyCar findCar(){
    MyCar car = CarManager.findCarById("U983"); //Nullpointer Exception here if no car be found
    if(car!=null)
        return car;
    else
        return null;

}
```

When I invoke the above function in Java, If the above `CarManager.findCarById()`  did not find any car, it returns `null`, and I try to check in `if condition` that if it is `null` return `null` other wise return the `car`.

But the `findCar()` function always stop and raise **Nullpointer Exception** when findCarById() did not find any car, without go through my `if condition`. How to get rid of it?

**============ findCarById() is a library API I can not modify =================**

Comment: Please add the code for CarManager.findCarById

Comment: Post the relevent CarManager code. Think your problem lies here

Comment: Wouldn't the answer to that be in the CarManager.findCarById() function?

Comment: The "find my errors" type of questions usually doesn't belong here....

Comment: Please check my update, findCarById() is a library API I can not modify

Comment: Do you have any document about CarManager at all? Seems like you're asking for it to return a car, but findCarById can't find the car and you get an NPE. If findCarById was able to return null your code should work. Pherhaps it's returning something else then null if it doesn't find the car

Comment: Did you check, that you use the library right? Did you forget to set something up (database, properties, etc ...). If this problem is persistent talk to the developer of that library and don't try to work around such a crucial problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Throwing or catching NullPointerException is not a really good idea. If you can modify that `findCarById`, change it.

Otherwise, you can do try-catch here.

```
MyCar car = null;
try {
   car = CarManager.findCarById("U983");
} catch (NullPointerException e) {
   car = null;
}
```

Comment: Please check my update, findCarById() is a library API I can not modify

Comment: catching nullpointerexceptions is evil

Comment: To be fair, it's really a) null that is evil, b) the writers of the external library who should be shot for throwing exceptions at you from a "find" method.

Comment: @oers That's is the problem with library API, it is forces what else we can do?

Comment: get someone to fix that library :D

Answer (score 0):

Check (or post) method "findCarById" in your static CarManager class.

Comment: Please check my update, findCarById() is a library API I can not modify

Answer (score 0):

You're saying that the `findCar()` method you posted is throwing a `NullPointerException`? That's not possible since there are no object dereferences in that method.

Also, that whole if condition is pointless. It's saying "if car is null, return null, else return the car". You might just as well say `return car;` - it will have exactly the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

How about modifying `findCar()` like this :

```
public MyCar findCar(){
    MyCar car = null;
    try {
        car = CarManager.findCarById("U983"); //Nullpointer Exception here if no car be    found   
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return car;
}
```

Comment: but cool eye-opener of mistakes !!!!